# keras ImageDataGenerator: size of augmented data?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I was trying to train some CNN using keras by first augmenting my image dataset (~2GB). When I executed:

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
featurewise_center=True, 
featurewise_std_normalization=True,
zca_whitening = True,
rotation_range = 90,
width_shift_range=0,
height_shift_range=0,
horizontal_flip = True,
vertical_flip=True
)
```

There appeared to be a `MemoryError`. (When I train my model without data augmentation, everything went smoothly.) But I couldn't figure out how much augmentation is allowed in my case. Could anyone kindly let me know how to calculate the size of the resulting augmented data argument by argument within the `ImageDataGenerator`?

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: What batch size do you use? Did you try smaller sizes?

Comment: @SergiiGryshkevych, thanks for your comment! I tried many batch sizes ~3-20. The memory error was consistent...

Comment: Are you able to control the number of generated images added to the original training set? Not sure if these images have to be all presented in memory. If so, at some point, you will exceed the the memory limit of your machine. If not, I think the limit might be your disk size.